# Filter over list with dynamically added filters

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to filter on a list of people where dynamically the filters can change. So the moment I want to filter by gender and role, I give those two filters. The moment I want to change this to role only or change the value of the role, another filtering must be performed on the list with the new filter. As soon as filtering is done, it is checked whether the person meets all the filters. So, for example, the filtering is done on the gender with the value true and role number 4. Then only the person 'Meike' is returned.

I have tried the following code. This code adds each person again as soon as he meets each individual filter, so it is possible that a person appears twice in the list. Of course this can be solved by checking whether he already exists in the list, but I wonder if the code below is 'the way to go' for this problem.

```
Dictionary<string, object> _filter = new();

List<Person> _people = new List<Person>();
_people.Add(new Person(1, "Bram", false, 4));
_people.Add(new Person(2, "Harry", false, 4));
_people.Add(new Person(3, "Meike", true, 4));
_people.Add(new Person(4, "Lisa", true, 3));
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

List<Person> secondPersonList = new();
Dictionary<string, object> secondFilter = new();
secondFilter.Add("Gender", true);
secondFilter.Add("Role", 3);

foreach (var filter in secondFilter)
{
    if(filter.Key == "Gender")
    {
        foreach (var person in _people.FindAll(x => x.Gender == (bool)filter.Value))
            secondPersonList.Add(person);
    }

    if (filter.Key == "Role")
    {
        foreach (var person in _people.FindAll(x => x.Role == (int)filter.Value))
            secondPersonList.Add(person);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Multiple filters");
foreach(Person person in secondPersonList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {person.Id}, Name: {person.Name}");
}
```

Person class:

```
internal class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }

    public Person(int id, string name, bool gender, int role)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Gender = gender;
        Role = role;
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment, your implementation does a logical OR on the filters: I.e., you get all people who are EITHER female OR have role 3. Are you sure that this is what you want? I ask because combining filter criteria with AND is more common.

Comment: @Heinzi The filters should indeed be combined with AND.

Comment: Then I have an answer for you (see answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about LINQ is that you can add filters "on the fly". Since you clarified in the comments that you actually want to combine the filters with `AND` instead of `OR`, I suggest the following:

```
IEnumerable<Person> filtered = _people;

foreach (var filter in secondFilter)
{
    switch (filter.Key)
    {
        case "Gender":
            filtered = filtered.Where(x => x.Gender == (bool)filter.Value));
            break;

        case "Role":
            filtered = filtered.Where(x => x.Role == (int)filter.Value));
            break;

        default:
            // something went wrong, you might want to throw an exception here.
    } 
}

// This will evaluate the filters and materialize the result
var secondPersonList = filtered.ToList();
```

(For readability, I have changed your `if` statements to a `switch` statement, but the former will work as well.)